# How to authorize particular users in wso2?

Tags: authentication, wso2, authorization, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am using Enterprise Integrator. I want to authorise customised users, using authentication service to have access tokens. I had tried "proxy service" method for this. But it isn't working.

How can I do this?

```
    <soapenv:Fault xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:axis2ns7="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soapenv:Code>
  <soapenv:Value>axis2ns7:Sender</soapenv:Value>
  <soapenv:Subcode>
    <soapenv:Value xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">wsse:InvalidSecurity</soapenv:Value>
  </soapenv:Subcode>
</soapenv:Code>
<soapenv:Reason>
  <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">Expected transport is "https" but incoming transport found : "http" </soapenv:Text>
</soapenv:Reason>
<soapenv:Detail/>
</soapenv:Fault>
```

Comment: You can do so by adding a security policy to the proxy service. Here is a sample tutorial: https://www.yenlo.com/blog/securing-proxies-in-wso2-esb-4.9.0

Comment: I tried what you have suggested. But still no positive response. I have attached the error in the question. Please see, if you can help.

Answer (score 1):

To secure a proxy service in WSO2, you should use a security policy.

Note: after the proxy service is secured, you should use https transport to access the proxy service and add the required authentication tokens in the soap header:

```
  <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">

         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-7DEBB9BDD57CC8619914970188232131">
            <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">TVea2PRqvZrMuX3edayHPGMHaB8=</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">cRkZQr9inPo9JbrD+nselw==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2017-06-09T14:33:43.212Z</wsu:Created>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
```

You can add users and roles using the Management Console: Configure - Users and Roles. You can also import users from other user stores: Configure - User Stores (or, alternatively, by modifying WSO2EI_FOLDER/conf/user-mgt.xml ).